# Ruby Gems with flexible gem dependencies?

Tags: ruby, dependencies, rubygems, bundler

I'm about to extract major functionality of a larger project into a ruby gem.

The little framework I created uses a few additional gems, for different import/export options. Ie.

- FasterCSV (for ruby 1.8) for csv import/export
- Nokogiri for csv import/export
- GraphViz for graph ...
- PDF
- ...

I don't want users of the gem to install and load all the gems when they don't need them.

Is that possible at all?

Comment: are you thinking of graphviz as a gem?

Comment: graphviz as in ruby-graphviz gem. not the best example

Answer (score 0):

The code in your initializer is just code... you could have your gem-user pass through a set of config options, and make the config.gem dependencies only load if those options are present. one way to do this would be to get them to set up global-values in config environemtn
eg in config/environment.rb:

```
CSV_EXPORTS = XML_EXPORTS = true
PDF_EXPORTS = false
```

Then in your own gem, you'd write:

```
config.gem 'fastercsv' if defined?(CSV_EXPORTS)
config.gem 'nokogiri'  if defined?(XML_EXPORTS)
if defined?(PDF_EXPORTS)
  config.gem 'prawn' 
  config.gem 'prawn-layout'
end
# etc
```

use "defined?" so that if they don't set up any at all, the gems won't try to load. It also means you can default them to whatever you like.